# Python Django To save the old request post value and use it later

Tags: python, django, post, request

I want to save the request post value and use it later
Do you know how to save the request value in Python and use it later?

**my_code(error)**

```
def send_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_target = request.POST['target']
        selected_template = request.POST['template']
```

Comment: What do you mean `use it later`? I would suggest storing it in the DB properly

Comment: @0sVoid
I understand how to get it from a.html and use it for b.html. However, I do not know how to retrieve the request.POST value received from two or more html.
Is the only way to save and load data into the db?

Comment: If by use it later you mean in a later session then yes, if not then there’s probably a way of doing it - hard to say because I don’t know what your use case is

Comment: You can store it in cookies and also set expiration time. That way, you will be able to use that data whenever you need.